# Настройка ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, django

Добрый день.
Подключил к проекту расширение django-ckeditor. Хочу немного настроить внешний вид редактора. В настройках содержимое панелей задаётся путём указания названия кнопки:

```
'toolbar_Basic': [
    ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
],
```

Мне нужно добавить кнопки выравнивания текста, но нигде не могу найти как они называются. Подскажите где мне искать эти названия?

---

Отвечаю сам себе

Поковырявшись немного остановился на таком способе:

- Идём на http://ckeditor.com/download и качаем полную версию.
- Открываем файл ckeditor/samples/plugins/toolbar/toolbar.html
- В самом низу находим раздел Full toolbar configuration со всеми названиями кнопок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У самого была такая проблема.Вот, что получилось нарыть:
'Source', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'BulletedList', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', 'Font', 'FontSize', 'TextColor', 'About', 'NewPage', 'Preview', 'Templates', 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', 'Undo', 'Redo', 'Strike', 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'BGColor', 'Liststyle', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList','Outdent','Indent','Blockquote'

Comment: Всем спасибо за участие, приму ваш ответ так как ваш рейтинг самый низкий. Надеюсь @NoName не в обиде :)

Answer (score 1):

```
'toolbar_Basic': [
      ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock']
 ];
```